# Date Format Conversion in Java

Tags: java, date

*I have a requirement in project* 
**to Convert 24 hours format to 12 hours format** 
for example 
**if it is 17:12:01 it should be converted to 05:12:01**

Comment: That requirement does not make much sense out of context.  You would never STORE a value that is not a complete, valid time.  You might want to DISPLAY such a value in 12-hour format.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to format it.

```
Date date = new Date(yourdate);
// format however you see fit
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String formatted = format.format(date);
```

As suggested by Software Monkey, also use a SimpleDateFormat to parse your 24hr date if you don't already have it in millis.

Comment: let make it more clear if it is 17 Dec 2010 17:02:24 it should be 17-Dec-10 05:02:24....this i need to store in db....as constraint set is 0-12 hours format

Answer (score 1):

Use two `SimpleDateFormat` objects - one to parse and the other to format the time.

Note also that `05:12:01` is not technically a 12 hour time (rather it appears to be an AM 24 hour time, given the lead 0 on the hour and the lack of a meridian designation).  You probably want `5:12:01 PM`.

It is *possible* that a 12 hour SimpleDateFormat will correctly parse a 24 hour time, provided that it is configured for lenient parsing.  Just saying, so perhaps you need only one SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: thanks to all above people for their answer...and i got the solution